# Lolcat picture on the error page only appears for a brief moment

Tags: bug, error-message

When you go to the [error page](https://stackoverflow.com/error) in Firefox, a picture of a lolcat appears for a brief moment:
[image: lolcat picture]

Before being replaced by a different picture like the one below:

> [image]

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In Firefox, a lolcat image loads, and then is immediately replaced by a different one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [here is what I see](https://media.giphy.com/media/l3q2xG1T4eR46lg5i/source.gif).

Comment: The lolcat is in a `<noscript>` node. Blame Firefox, I guess.

Comment: @deceze You need to wait a bit more time to see lolcat in my gif.

Comment: @Veve look into [it](https://media.giphy.com/media/l3q2xG1T4eR46lg5i/source.gif). Just wait about 10sec.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lolcat picture appearing briefly on the error page when browsing https://stackoverflow.com/error with Firefox (v50.1), it's in a `noscript` tag:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px">
    <noscript>
        &lt;img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" width="500" alt=""&gt; 
    </noscript>
    <img id="error-cat" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/263319349.jpg" class="" width="500">
</div>
```

But as Javascript is activated on (my) browser, it shouldn't been shown.

Comment: That sounds like a browser issue.